# Rails: In Application Controller, force login, redirect all requests except login

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, redirect, request, applicationcontroller

I'd like a simple method in my application controller that requires all users to log in before continuing to any part of the site. I'm using Devise for authentication.

I tried:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  ...
  unless user_signed_in?
    redirect_to login_path
  end
  ...
end
```

This successfully redirects everyone, but the problem is it also prevents the post request necessary to create a new user session.

So my question is, how would you go about blocking all requests except for the login view and the post request for logging in?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using Devise this is easy.  You just need to add `before_filter :authenticate_user!` to your ApplicationController.

This is all spelled out in the Devise wiki - https://github.com/plataformatec/devise

Note that in Rails 4.2+, `before_action :authenticate_user!` is preferred.

Comment: Oh of course. I have this in many (but not all) of the controllers already... I was thinking too hard about how to lock down the entire site temporarily and not thinking enough about application controller being just a regular controller. Thanks :)

Comment: For the most part you'll want to just throw that line into ApplicationController and then skip the before filter for the actions you want to white list.